# Django admin makes a lot of duplicate queries in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

I have encountered a problem.

When I try to open the change page in order to see parameters within element (like `djangosite.com/admin/djangoapp/someelement/1/change/`) it loads very slowly (10-15 seconds).

I found out that Django is making a lot of duplicate queries:

**UPDATE:**
I think I made mistake in admin.py.

```
   inlines = [PhoneInline,FlatInline,NeedInline]
```

If i delete line above everything is fine.

mysql log

```
2161 Query  set autocommit=0
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_phone`.`id`, `ha_phone`.`phone_number`, `ha_phone`.`phone_owner_id` FROM `ha_phone` WHERE `ha_phone`.`id` = 262
         2161 Query SELECT `django_content_type`.`id`, `django_content_type`.`app_label`, `django_content_type`.`model` FROM `django_content_type` WHERE (`django_content_type`.`model` = 'phone' AND `django_content_type`.`app_label` = 'MYAPP')
         2161 Query commit
         2161 Query set autocommit=1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_owner`.`id`, `ha_owner`.`owner_pub_date`, `ha_owner`.`owner_name`, `ha_owner`.`owner_verify`, `ha_owner`.`owner_company_id` FROM `ha_owner` WHERE `ha_owner`.`id` = 236
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_owner`.`id`, `ha_owner`.`owner_pub_date`, `ha_owner`.`owner_name`, `ha_owner`.`owner_verify`, `ha_owner`.`owner_company_id` FROM `ha_owner`
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1
         2161 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company` WHERE `ha_company`.`id` = 1

...
```

models.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Номер дома")
    house_floors = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Число этажей", null=True)
    house_walls = models.ForeignKey(Walls, verbose_name="Материал стен", null=True)
    house_street = models.ForeignKey(Street, verbose_name="Улица")
    house_metro = models.ForeignKey(Metro, verbose_name="Станция Метро", null=True)
    house_block = models.ForeignKey(Block, verbose_name="Микрорайон", null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Дом'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Дома'
        ordering = ['house_street','house_number']


    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.house_street.street_name) + " " + unicode(self.house_number)

class Flat(models.Model):
    flat_number = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name="Номер квартиры", null=True)
    flat_rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Число комнат")
    flat_total_sq = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Общая площадь")
    flat_life_sq = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Жилая площадь")
    flat_kitchen_sq = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Кухонная площадь")
    flat_floors = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Этаж")
    flat_house = models.ForeignKey(House, verbose_name="Дом")
    flat_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, verbose_name="Владелец")
    flat_comment = models.TextField(verbose_name="Комметарий", null=True)
    flat_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена квартиры')
...    
class Owner(models.Model):
        owner_pub_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,verbose_name="Дата публикации")
        owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="ФИО владельца")
        owner_verify = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Пользователь верифицирован?")
        owner_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name="Компания")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Владельца'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Владельцы'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.id) + " | "+ self.owner_name + " " + unicode(self.owner_company)


    class Phone(models.Model):
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Номер телефона")
        phone_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, verbose_name="Владелец телефона")

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Телефон'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Телефоны'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.phone_owner) + " " + self.phone_number
```

admin.py

```
...        
class PhoneInline(admin.StackedInline):
            model = Phone
            extra = 2

        class FlatInline(admin.TabularInline):
            model = Flat
            extra = 0

        class NeedInline(admin.TabularInline):
            model = Need
            extra = 1

        class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            field=['owner_name']
            inlines = [PhoneInline,FlatInline,NeedInline]

    admin.site.register(Owner,OwnerAdmin)
```

What should I do?
Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**
@Alasdair, thank you. Queries with ha_company are reduced. But I have another duplicates with ha_street. Looks like this:

```
 2601 Query SELECT `ha_company`.`id`, `ha_company`.`company_name` FROM `ha_company`
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_house`.`id`, `ha_house`.`house_number`, `ha_house`.`house_floors`, `ha_house`.`house_walls_id`, `ha_house`.`house_street_id`, `ha_house`.`house_metro_id`, `ha_house`.`house_block_id`, `ha_house`.`house_age`, `ha_house`.`house_flat`, `ha_house`.`house_quality` FROM `ha_house` INNER JOIN `ha_street` ON (`ha_house`.`house_street_id` = `ha_street`.`id`) ORDER BY `ha_street`.`street_name` ASC, `ha_house`.`house_number` ASC
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_street`.`id`, `ha_street`.`street_name` FROM `ha_street` WHERE `ha_street`.`id` = 74
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_street`.`id`, `ha_street`.`street_name` FROM `ha_street` WHERE `ha_street`.`id` = 74
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_street`.`id`, `ha_street`.`street_name` FROM `ha_street` WHERE `ha_street`.`id` = 36
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_street`.`id`, `ha_street`.`street_name` FROM `ha_street` WHERE `ha_street`.`id` = 582
         2601 Query SELECT `ha_street`.`id`, `ha_street`.`street_name` FROM `ha_street` WHERE `ha_street`.`id` = 582
```

Comment: if your solution is ok just answer your own question so people will find it more easily

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__unicode__` method for the `Phone` model includes `unicode(self.phone_owner)`, which in turn accesses the `owner_company` foreign key. That means that Django has to look up the company for every phone object in the inline.

You fixed the problem by removing the inline, but if you want to keep the inline you could either:

1. Change the `__unicode__` method for `Phone` or `Owner` so that the company is not included
2. Override the `get_queryset` method for your inline, so that you can use `select_related`.

   ```
   class PhoneInline(admin.StackedInline):
       model = Phone
       extra = 2

       def get_queryset(self, request):
           return super(PhoneInline, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('phone_owner', 'phone_owner__ owner_company')
   ```

Comment: thank you. It helps. But I've had the same problem with ha_street. How I should rewrite this:
`unicode(self.house_street.street_name)` ? Is this the problem?

Comment: It's a similar issue, it looks like your query is looking up the street for every house in a queryset. You can either remove `self.house_street` from the `__unicode__` method, or use `select_related`. You haven't shown the model admins or said which url is causing those queries so I can't say how to do this.

Comment: I've added model admins in the question above. The problem is in the owner change page in django admin. I think that the reason in FlatInline

Comment: If the problem is the `FlatInline`, then override its `get_queryset` method and use `select_related`. You might want to rethink whether you want to include foreign keys in your `__unicode__` methods. If the `Flat.__unicode__` method uses itself, its house and the house's street, then you need to be very careful to prevent a large number of SQL queries.